# XSD for XML file that has xs:all followed by xs:choice or xs:sequence

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I have an XML file that looks like the following:

```
<root>
    <node1></node1>
    <node2></node2>
    <node3></node3>
    <line>
       <line1></line1>
       <line2></line2>
       <line3></line3>
    </line>
    <line>
       <line1></line1>
       <line2></line2>
       <line3></line3>
    </line>
</root>
```

Here are my restrictions:

- `<node1>`,`<node2>`,`<node3>` must each occur exactly once and may occur in
  any order
- `<node1>`,`<node2>`,`<node3>` must all occur prior to the beginning of the
  `<line>` elements
- There are an arbitrary number of `<line>` elements, but there must be at least one
- `<line1>`,`<line2>`,`<line3>` elements in `<line>` must each occur exactly once and may occur in any order
- I have no control over the XML. It's being given to me by some third-party software.
- I have to use XSD 1.0.
- This is a simplified example. I'm looking at 20 or so unique `<node#>`s, so the solution has to scale well.

I'm trying to design an XSD file to validate this XML, but to no avail. The problem is that I'm essentially looking at an `<xs:all>` block (for my `<node#>`s) followed by an `<xs:sequence>` or `<xs:choice>` block with `maxOccurs="unbounded"` (for my `<line>`s), but it seems like there's no valid way to do this with XSD 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only six possible sequences of (1,2,3) appearing once each in any order, so it's feasible to enumerate them all. Of course this doesn't scale but it might work for you. That would be

```
(1((2,3)|(3,2)) | 2((1,3)|(3,1)) | 3((1,2)|(2,1))
```

using "," for sequence and "|" for choice.

Your only other options are not XSD 1.0. E.g. XSD 1.1 or schematron.

Comment: No, it doesn't scale well, and I need it to scale well. My example above was simplified. It's a shame that XSD 1.0 is so limiting, especially since it seems like this is the kind of situation that would crop up a lot. However, I'm glad that XSD 1.1 tried to address some of those issues.

Comment: There's a very strong culture in XSD (and perhaps other schema languages) that says: "here's a kit of tools for designing good XML documents. Use them to design your document". As opposed to: "design your document any way you like, and then use our tools to describe your design" - which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: I understand. If I had the freedom to design the XML document myself, I would have done it in a much more XSD-friendly way. I'm learning that the language assumes the creator of the XSD is also the creator of the XML, which is not the case here.